# vue + checkbox + change event - different results on page and in console

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox, onchange

I have an issue I can't understand and solve.
I have simple page in vue - set of checkboxes bound via v-model to array.
This is how it looks like:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <b-form-checkbox-group
      switches
      stacked
      v-model="selectedFruits"
      :options="options"
      @change="selectionChanged"
    >
    </b-form-checkbox-group>
    {{ selectedFruits }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      selectedFruits: [],
      options: [
        {
          text: 'Apple',
          value: {id: 1, val: 'apple'},
        },
        {
          text: 'Banana',
          value: {id: 2, val: 'banana'},
        },
        {
          text: 'Pear',
          value: {id: 3, val: 'pear'},
        },
        {
          text: 'Plum',
          value: {id: 4, val: 'plum'},
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectionChanged() {
      console.log(this.selectedFruits);
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Nothing difficult, as you can see.

It works great on the screen - `{{ selectedFruits }}` are displayed correctly.
But when I check the value of `selectedFuits` in console I see different results than displayed - console shows "one click late" results.
Can you explain the issue and direct me, how to solve it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're dumping the value right before Vue updates it. If you want to be in sync with Vue, you should `watch` the variable instead of implementing your own `@change`:

```
<b-form-checkbox-group
  switches
  stacked
  v-model="selectedFruits"
  :options="options"
>

...

watch: {
  selectedFruits(val) {
    console.log(val); // or this.selectedFruits
  }
}
```

You could also probably use `Vue.nextTick(() => console.log(this.selectedFruits))` with your current code, but still, when you're using v-model, I think you should not implement your own events for the same thing.

(an aside: v-model just listens for `@input` - it's possible `b-form-checkbox-group` just emits this before emitting `@change`. with `watch`, you don't have to care about this kind of detail because it is synced with Vue's update cycle)

Comment: Thank you. Both answers solved the issue.
Now the question is, which one should I use? In my solution I have a modal with component inside, and there I have checkboxes, and I emit "change" event on every checkbox change. 
I guess I can emit the event both from my method and from watch - now, is there a rule which should I use? Or it does not matter as long as my solution works? :)

Comment: @Mikk in terms of consuming the event, if you set a v-model, you should not have other listeners, because `watch` is correct (and it covers _any_ changes to that variable). Now, if you want to inform the parent above you about the change, you could `$emit('change')` from your `watch` callback. If you find yourself re-emitting events a lot (more than 1 level up through the tree), you might want to look at a centralized store like Vuex

Comment: thank you again. You're right - there is no need for new event when there is already one that does the same as my custom event.